# bic.glm predict error: "newdata is missing variables"

Tags: r

I've spent a lot of time trying to solve this error and searching for solutions without any luck, and I thank you in advance for your help.

I'm trying to create predicted values from the coefficients created via BMA. Whenever I run my predict function, I am getting a "newdata is missing variables" error. All variables included in the original model are present in the new dataframe, so I'm not quite sure what the problem is. I'm working with a fairly large dataset with many independent variables. I'm fairly new to R, so I apologize if this is an obvious question!

```
y<-df$y
x<-df
x$y<-NULL
bic.glm<-bic.glm(x, y, strict=FALSE, OR=20, glm.family="binomial", factortype=TRUE)
predict(bic.glm.bwt, x)
```

I've also tried it this way:

```
bic.glm<-bic.glm(y~., data=df, strict=FALSE, OR=20, glm.family="binomial", factortype=TRUE)
predict(bic.glm, x)
```

And also with creating a new data frame...

```
bic.glm<-bic.glm(y~., data=df, strict=FALSE, OR=20, glm.family="binomial", factortype=TRUE)
newdata<-x
predict(bic.glm, newdata=x)
```

Each time I receive the same error message:
   Error in predict.bic.glm(bic.glm, newdata=x) :
   newdata is missing variables

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

First, it is bad practice to call your LHS the same name as the function call. You may be masking the function `bic.glm` from further use.

That minor comment aside... I just encountered the same error. After some digging, it seems that `predict.bic.glm` checks the names vs. the `mle` matrix in the `bic.glm` object. The problem is that somewhere in `bic.glm`, if factors are used, those names get a '.x' or just '.' appended at the end. Therefore, whenever you use factors you will get this error.

I communicated this to package maintainers. Meanwhile, you can work around the bug by renaming the column names of the `mle` object, like this (using your example):

```
fittedBMA<-bic.glm(y~., data=df) 
colnames(fittedBMA$mle)=colnames(model.matrix(y~., data=df)) ### this is the workaround
predict(fittedBMA,newdata=x) ### should work now, if x has the same variables as df
```

Comment: I had the same problem today: the package is still unchanged. Your solution worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so first look at the usage section in the cran documentation for BMA::bic.glm.

[here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BMA/BMA.pdf)

This example is instructive for a data.frame.

```
Example 2 (binomial)
library(MASS)
data(birthwt)
y <- birthwt$lo
x <- data.frame(birthwt[,-1])
x$race <- as.factor(x$race)
x$ht <- (x$ht>=1)+0
x <- x[,-9]
x$smoke <- as.factor(x$smoke)
x$ptl <- as.factor(x$ptl)
x$ht <- as.factor(x$ht)
x$ui <- as.factor(x$ui)
bic.glm.bwT <- bic.glm(x, y, strict = FALSE, OR = 20,
glm.family="binomial",
factor.type=TRUE)
predict( bic.glm.bwT, newdata = x)
bic.glm.bwF <- bic.glm(x, y, strict = FALSE, OR = 20,
glm.family="binomial",
factor.type=FALSE)
predict( bic.glm.bwF, newdata = x)
```